# Android - I want my Keyboard to work only on a list of user specified activities

Tags: android, android-input-method

I have my keyboard working on every activity, but I am not getting any good way to make it run on specific activities of different apps.

> Is there a way to check the activity running and open the keyboard there if it is in my list?

Comment: Could you please go more into detail, for example provide some code, in your question? I can't see your problem, what you try to get from us.

Answer (score 0):

No.

First, you have no reliable way to "check the activity running", for privacy and security reasons, particularly on newer versions of Android.

Second, the **user** decides what input method editor to choose, as a default and on a situational basis. **You** do not get a vote, again for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: In case the user selects my keyboard as default, can I make it not work at some activities?

Comment: @ShubhanshAasu: You cannot prevent your keyboard from appearing in all activities, if the user chooses it as a default. Also, I do not see a way for you to determine what activity invoked your keyboard.